# Why I am getting runtime NZEC error in CodeChef?

Tags: python, runtime-error, runtime

You are given an integer C
. Let d
be the smallest integer such that 2d
is strictly greater than C
.

Consider all pairs of non-negative integers (A,B)
such that A,B<2d
and A⊕B=C
(⊕
denotes the bitwise XOR operation). Find the maximum value of A⋅B
over all these pairs.
I have tried the below code but its giving runtime NZEC error.

```
def msb(c):
    for i in range(63,0,-1):
        if (c & (1<<i)):
            return i
            break
while(True):
    try:
        t = int(input())
        for i in range(t):
            c=int(input())
            m=msb(c)
            a=0
            b=0
            for j in range(m+1):
                ci=(c>>j & 1)
                if ci==0:
                    a=a | (1<<j)
                    b=b | (1<<j)
                elif j==m:
                    a=a | (1<<j)
                    b=b & ~(1<<j)
                elif ci==1:
                    a=a & ~(1<<j)
                    b=b | (1<<j)
            print(a*b)

    except EOFError:
        break
```

Comment: Do you execute the code in an online coding platform? Or if not which python version do you use? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nzec-error-python/

Comment: I have used codechef online editor. The code is working fine in CS50 IDE but when I run it in the codechef editor it's showing this runtime nzec error. I followed their input and output format also.For custom input it's working fine in the codechef editor but when i run it for all the testcases then its giving this error.